# Литературный вариант слова "зажрался"

Tags: одним-словом

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературный вариант сленгового слова "зажрался".

Я понимаю его значение как "пресыщен успехами и слишком хорошим уровнем жизни".

Есть ли вариант короче?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от контекста похожий смысл может иметь *избаловáлся*. Можно ещё написать *засибарúтствовался*, но это слово акцентирует "хороший уровень жизни" и почти не имеет коннотации "успех" (я не уверен, что эта коннотация так уж сильна в исходном *зажрался*).

Comment: Что значит слово "засибарúтствовался"? Родился и 25 лет прожил в культурной столице, и ни разу не встречал этого слова.

Comment: @Alexander Perechnev: I hope you are not banned on the Internet? [Cибаритствовать](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 9):

Помимо *избаловался* - *заелся*, *пресытился*.

В зависимости от контекста: *обнаглел*, *потерял стыд*.

Comment: _пресытился_  подразумевает, что уже больше ничего не хочется.       
_зажрался_ же может означать как потерю желаний (_я совсем зажрался/пресытился, новые игры даже не открываю_), так их эскалацию (_совсем зажрался/избаловался/обнаглел, все ему новинки подавай_).

Answer (score -1):

"зарвался" - грубо вышел за рамки дозволенного.